# Nivo Slider not showing images in Drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, nivo-slider

I am trying to add Nivo Image Slider on my front page in drupal theme running on localhost. I am using an existing druapl 6 theme template as my base theme.
I followed all the steps given on the following website on how to install nivo slider.
http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-and-set-up-nivo-slider

However when I run the site, the images are not loaded and the slider box just shows the processing i.e the round symbol moving

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make my own images appear in the slider?

Answer (score -1):

this link is wrong!

you can see source of page (with firebug) and search for what happened that make images not showing.

I think problem is on *src* attribute.you should notify,the url of image is relative and fill with php code.

Comment: The src attribute shows the following: http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/imagecache/original-image/ where I can see the two images that I added. I am not much of a php guy so I do not really know how to notify that the url of image is relative. Is there any other way to achieve this?